# How to save photo to contacts application in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I use the following method to store the phone number and email-id to the contacts application.

```
/**
     * Phone number.
     */
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone_Num)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
            .build());
    /**
     * Business Email
     */
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, web)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
            .build());
```

I also would like to save the photo to the contacts. How can I accomplish this similar to what I did above?

Comment: Please read this http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Android Contacts application also have a feature for Adding Photo to any contact and you might get the idea about this here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/froyo-release/src/com/android/contacts/AttachImage.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/froyo-release